# How am I suppoed to use callback or setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, express, callback

I need to push data from fileExistance into result and exports the result to budget.js in router folder. but I get this error message

```
internal/validators.js:189

throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK(callback);
^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received []
    at setTimeout (timers.js:121:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jaemin Windows10\GitHub\Jae_tasks\controller\budget.js:18:25)
```

```
const fs = require('fs');

var result = [];

const fileExistance = () => {
    fs.readdir('./data/budget', function(err, files) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else if(!files.length) {
            return "No Transaction history";
        } else { 
            console.log("file Existance " + files);
            result.push(files);
        }
    });
}
fileExistance();
console.log("result " + setTimeout(result, 1000));
exports.result = result;
```

This is budget.js in router folder

```js
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const fs = require('fs');

var budgetController = require('./../controller/budget');


console.log("result " + budgetController.result);

router.get('/budget', (req, res, next) => {
   const result =  budgetController.result;
   console.log(result);
    res.render('budget', {
    prods: result,
    pageTitle: 'Budget',
    path:'/budget',
    hasResults: result.length > 0,
    activeBudget: true,
    productCSS: true
  });
});

router.post('/budget', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log({title: req.body.title}.title);
    filePath.push({title: req.body.title}.title);
    res.redirect('/budget');
});

exports.router = router;
```

budget.js in router folder does get data into result. and I don't know much how to use callback and I am very new in Javascript.
How am I supposed to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

budget.js in controller folder

```
const fs = require('fs');

let fileExistance = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.readdir('./data/budget', function(err, files) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else if(!files.length) {
            resolve("No Transaction history");
        } else { 
            console.log("file Existance " + files);
           resolve(files);
        }
    });
});


exports.fileExistance = fileExistance;
```

budget.js in router folder

```
router.get('/budget', (req, res, next) => {
      budgetController.fileExistance.then(function(data){
      console.log(data[0])
      res.render('budget', {
      prods: data,
      pageTitle: 'Budget',
      path:'/budget',
      hasData: data.length > 0,
      activeBudget: true,
      productCSS: true
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code currently has a race condition. `fs.readdir` is what is called an asyncronous function as it takes some time to do what it needs to do. Because of this, you told `fs.readdir` "Hey, go do what you need to do, and "call me back" when you are ready. When you are ready, do what I specified in `function(err, files) {`

You are importing the first file but there is no guarantee that it will have populated the result in any time period. If your route is used really quickly, result will be blank.

What you will need to do is turn `fileExistance` into a function that takes a callback after it has populated results. A function that does this is a function that returns what is called a `Promise`.

I suggest you play around and understand javascript promises before moving forward.

Good luck!